# NumPy style arrays for C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dynamic-arrays

Are there any C++ (or C) libs that have NumPy-like arrays with support for slicing, vectorized operations, adding and subtracting contents element-by-element, etc.?

Comment: [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: As far as I know numpy uses [LAPACK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK). While that is written in Fortran, there are c++ bindings available. Never used either of those though.

Comment: There is a recent C++ interface to NumPy, called [ArmaNpy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/armanpy/).

Comment: I can't see [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) in the comments yet

Comment: You could try embedding Python and actually using numpy which would have the advantage of not needing to learn a new library, though it'd be slower than using a C/C++ library.

Comment: This is an invaluable software coding question. Why was this closed????

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Because a lot of good questions get closed on stackoverflow

Comment: When converting NumPy Python code to C++ I find `std::valarray` quite helpful. It's in the standard library and support slicing, arithmetic operations to all elements and operations between two valarrays.

Comment: Jesus, why has nobody told me about `std::valarray` before...?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Here are several free software that may suit your needs.

1. The [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) is a GPL software written in C. Thus, it has a C-like allocation and way of programming (pointers, etc.). With the [GSLwrap](http://gslwrap.sourceforge.net/), you can have a C++ way of programming, while still using the GSL. GSL has a [BLAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) implementation, but you can use [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) instead of the default CBLAS, if you want even more performances.
2. The [boost/uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) library is a BSL library, written in C++ and distributed as a boost package. It is a C++-way of implementing the BLAS standard. uBLAS comes with a few linear algebra functions, and there is an [experimental binding to ATLAS](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/cgi-bin/boost_wiki/wiki.pl?Linear_Algebra_With_UBLAS).
3. [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) is a linear algebra library written in C++, distributed under the MPL2 license (starting from version 3.1.1) or LGPL3/GPL2 (older versions). It's a C++ way of programming, but more integrated than the two others (more algorithms and data structures are available). Eigen [claims to be faster](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#How_does_Eigen_compare_to_BLAS.2FLAPACK.3F) than the BLAS implementations above, while not following the de-facto standard BLAS API. Eigen does not seem to put a lot of effort on parallel implementation.
4. [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) is LGPL3 library for C++. It has binding for [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) (the library used by numpy). It uses recursive templates and template meta-programming, which is a good point (I don't know if other libraries are doing it also?).
5. [xtensor](https://github.com/QuantStack/xtensor) is a C++ library that is BSD licensed. It offers A C++ API very similar to that of NumPy. See https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/numpy.html for a cheat sheet.

These alternatives are really good if you just want to get data structures and basic linear algebra. Depending on your taste about style, license or sysadmin challenges (installing big libraries like LAPACK may be difficult), you may choose the one that best suits your needs.

Comment: Believe it or not, my answer is the result of my own search, some month ago. I was believing that gathering the informations that helped me make my choice would be of some interest. I'm not sure wether it is better to have several informations spread across answers. You can still upvote everyone if you feel more concerned by ethic than efficiency.

Comment: Sadly, none of these provide anything as general and convenient as numpy arrays. Numpy arrays are arbitrary-dimensional and support things like `a[:4,::-1,:,19] = b[None,-5:,None]` or `a[a>5]=0` and similar, as well as having a huge set of array and index manipulation functions available. I really hope somebody makes something like that for C++ some day.

Comment: OpenCV also has a Matrix type that can have arbitrary dimensional size; column/row ranges  (`a.colRange(4,7).rowRange(4,8)` for `a[4:7,4,8]`) and condition mask (`a.setTo(cv::Scalar(0), a>5)` for `a[a>5]=0`)

Comment: @amaurea check out the answer on xtensor below, which enables all of the above.

Comment: I've had to use Eigen in a recent project and I have to say that while it seems to be efficient, the syntax is absolutely terrible. There is none of that amazing Python slicing syntax available. For example, if you have a 1D vector x and want to manipulate the first n elements, you have to use x.head(n). Don't even ask about manipulating an arbitrary slice of x, you'll need a good old for-loop to do that. This is just one of the many clunky and inconvenient examples I could name.

Comment: @amaurea the newer answer below about [xtensor](http://quantstack.net/xtensor) might grant your wish

Answer (score 66):

Try out [xtensor](http://quantstack.net/xtensor). (See the [NumPy to Xtensor Cheat Sheet](http://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/numpy.html)).

xtensor is a C++ library meant for numerical analysis with multi-dimensional array expressions.

**xtensor provides**

- an extensible expression system enabling numpy-style broadcasting.
- an API following the idioms of the C++ standard library.
- tools to manipulate array expressions and build upon xtensor.

**Example**

**Initialize a 2-D array and compute the sum of one of its rows and a 1-D array.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xio.hpp"

xt::xarray<double> arr1
  {{1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
   {2.0, 5.0, 7.0},
   {2.0, 5.0, 7.0}};

xt::xarray<double> arr2
  {5.0, 6.0, 7.0};

xt::xarray<double> res = xt::view(arr1, 1) + arr2;

std::cout << res;
```

Outputs

```
{7, 11, 14}
```

**Initialize a 1-D array and reshape it inplace.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xio.hpp"

xt::xarray<int> arr
  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

arr.reshape({3, 3});

std::cout << arr;
```

Outputs

```
{{1, 2, 3},
 {4, 5, 6},
 {7, 8, 9}}
```

Comment: @Llamageddon do you think this should be the selected answer ?

Answer (score 8):

[DyND](https://github.com/libdynd/libdynd) is designed to be, among other things, a NumPy-like library for C++. Things like broadcasting, arithmetic operators, and slicing all work fine. On the other hand, it is still *very* experimental and many features haven't been implemented yet.

Here's a simple implementation of the de Casteljau algorithm in C++ using DyND arrays:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dynd/array.hpp>

using namespace dynd;

nd::array decasteljau(nd::array a, double t){
    size_t e = a.get_dim_size();
    for(size_t i=0; i < e-1; i++){
        a = (1.-t) * a(irange()<(e-i-1)) + t * a(0<irange());
    }
    return a;
}

int main(){
    nd::array a = {1., 2., 2., -1.};
    std::cout << decasteljau(a, .25) << std::endl;
}
```

I wrote a [blog post](http://insertinterestingnamehere.github.io/posts/basic-examples.html) a little while back with more examples and side-by-side comparisons of the syntax for Fortran 90, DyND in C++, and NumPy in Python.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the current DyND developers.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question. Still felt like answering. Thought might help many, Especially pydevs coding in C++.

If you have already worked with python numpy, then [NumCpp](https://github.com/dpilger26/NumCpp) is a great choice. It's minimalistic in syntax and has got similar functions or methods as py numpy.

The [comparison](https://github.com/dpilger26/NumCpp#from-numpy-to-numcpp--a-quick-start-guide) part in the readme doc is also very very cool.

> NumCpp

```
nc::NdArray<int> arr = {{4, 2}, {9, 4}, {5, 6}};
arr.reshape(5, 3);
arr.astype<double>();
```

Answer (score 6):

Use LibTorch (PyTorch frontend for C++) and be happy.

Comment: Any examples to do something like this: a[:4,::-1,:,19] = b[None,-5:,None]

Comment: @Cypher Answer: `a.index({Slice(None, 4), Slice(None, None, -1), Slice(), 19}) = b.index({None, Slice(-5, None), None})` Docs: https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/notes/tensor_indexing.html

Comment: Thanks. I wish there was a better syntactic way to do this. Doesn't Operator Overloading in C++ allow to achieve something like what Numpy Arrays do?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use multidimensional array(like numpy) for image processing or neural network, you can use `OpenCV` `cv::Mat` along with tons of image processing algorithms. In case you just want to use it for matrix operations ONLY, you just have to compile respective opencv modules to reduce the size and have tiny OpenCV library.

`cv::Mat`(Matrix) is an n-dimensional array that can be used to store various type of data, such as RGB, HSV or grayscale images, vectors with real or complex values, other matrices etc.

A Mat contains the following information: `width, height, type, channels, data, flags, datastart, dataend` and so on.

It has several methods for matrix manipulation. Bonus you can create then on CUDA cores as well as `cv::cuda::GpuMat`.

Consider I want to create a matrix with 10 rows, 20 columns, type CV_32FC3:

```
int R = 10, C = 20;
Mat m1; 
m1.create(R, C, CV_32FC3); //creates empty matrix

Mat m2(cv::Size(R, C), CV_32FC3); // creates a matrix with R rows, C columns with data type T where R and C are integers, 

Mat m3(R, C, CV_32FC3); // same as m2
```

BONUS:

Compile [tiny and compact opencv](https://mdeore.medium.com/opencv-on-android-tiny-with-optimization-enabled-932460acfe38) library for just matrix operations. One of the ways is like as mentioned in this article.

OR

compile opencv source code using following cmake command:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
$ cd opencv
$ git checkout <version you want to checkout>
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D WITH_MATLAB=OFF -D BUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -D BUILD_opencv_objdetect=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_video=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_features2d=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_flann=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_highgui=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_ml=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_photo=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_python=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_shape=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_stitching=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_superres=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_ts=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_videostab=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_dnn=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_imgproc=OFF ..
$ make -j $nproc
$ sudo make install
```

Try this example:

```
 #include "opencv2/core.hpp"
 #include<iostream>

 int main()
 {
     std::cout << "OpenCV Version " << CV_VERSION << std::endl;

     int R = 2, C = 4;
     cv::Mat m1;
     m1.create(R, C, CV_32FC1); //creates empty matrix

     std::cout << "My Mat : \n" << m1 << std::endl;
 }
```

Compile the code with following command:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 opencv_mat.cc -o opencv_mat `pkg-config --libs opencv` `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
```

Run the executable:

```
$ ./opencv_mat

OpenCV Version 3.4.2
My Mat :
[0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Eigen is a good linear algebra library.

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

It is quite easy to install since it's a header-only library. It relies on template in order to to generate well optimized code. It vectorizes automatically the matrix operations.

It also fully support coefficient wise operations, such as the "per element multiplication" between two matrices for instance. It is what you need?

Comment: The syntax of Eigen is pretty terrible though. There is none of that smooth slicing syntax you find in Numpy. And it's not a general n-dimensional array library, it's more for 1D vectors and 2D matrices only. The fact that they have VectorXd for 1D arrays and MatrixXd for 2D arrays repels me already.

Comment: There is an "unsupported" tensor implementation in Eigen for n-d arrays however not as intuitive to use as numpy.ndarray

Answer (score 3):

xtensor is good, but I ended up writing a mini-library myself as a toy project with c++20, while trying to keep the interface as simple as possible. Here it is: https://github.com/gbalduzz/NDArray

Example code:

```
using namespace nd;
NDArray<int, 2> m(3, 3); // 3x3 matrix
m = 2; // assign 2 to all
m(-1, all) = 1; // assign 1 to the last row.

auto tile = m(range{1, end}, range{1, end}); // 2x2 tile
std::sort(tile.begin(), tile.end());

std::cout << m; // prints [[2, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 2]]
```

<s>It does not provide fancy arithmetic operators collapsing multiple operations together, yet, but</s> you can broadcast arbitrary lambdas to a set of tensors with the same shape, or use lazily evaluated arithmetic operators.

Let me know what do you think about the interface and how it compares with the other options, and if this has any hope, what sort of operations you would like to see implemented.

Free license and no dependency!

Addendum: I managed to properly compile and run xtensor, and the result is that my library is significantly faster when iterating over views (2 to 3X)

Answer (score 2):

[Blitz++](http://blitz.sourceforge.net/) supports arrays with an arbitrary number of axes, whereas Armadillo only supports up to three (vectors, matrices, and cubes).  Eigen only supports vectors and matrices (not cubes).  The downside is that Blitz++ doesn't have linear algebra functions beyond the basic entrywise operations and tensor contractions.  Development seems to have slowed down quite some time ago, but perhaps that's just because the library does what it does and not many changes need to be made.

Answer (score 2):

VIGRA contains a good N-dimensional array implementation:

http://ukoethe.github.io/vigra/doc/vigra/Tutorial.html

I use it extensively, and find it very simple and effective. It's also header only, so very easy to integrate into your development environment. It's the closest thing I've come across to using NumPy in terms of it's API.

The main downside is that it isn't so widely used as the others, so you won't find much help online. That, and it's awkwardly named (try searching for it!)

Answer (score 1):

While [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.7/index.html) is designed to mesh easily with OpenGL and GLSL, it is a fully functional header only math library for C++ with a very intuitive set of interfaces.

It declares vector & matrix types as well as various operations on them.

Multiplying two matrices is a simple as (M1 * M2). Subtracting two vectors (V1- V2).

Accessing values contained in vectors or matrices is equally simple. After declaring a vec3 vector for example, one can access its first element with vector.x.  Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

[Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) is a template library for linear algebra (matrices, vectors…). It is header only and free to use (LGPL).

Answer (score 0):

The [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) is great, it does all of what you're asking and much more.  It is licensed under the GPL though.