# Numpy `.view` function in C++

Tags: python, c++, numpy

I'm trying to convert a string into int32 in C++. In Python, I used to do:

```
import numpy as np
str = "HELLO"
np.array([str]).view(np.int32)
```

This results in:

```
array([72, 69, 76, 76, 79], dtype=int32)
```

i.e., the `ord` of each char.

How can I achieve the same in C++?

P. S. I'm not looking for Numpy-style way to accomplish this. But, looking for possible ways to obtain the same results.

Comment: To the downvoter, would you please post any comment regarding what is wrong with the question so that I can avoid in further questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NumPy style arrays for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169418/numpy-style-arrays-for-c)

Comment: @zvone Nope, would you please read the new note I added?

Comment: So, you just want to convert string to int? Use [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/). BTW, also in Python I would not use numpy for that. I would just do `int(s)`.

Comment: Man, have you really read the question. I'm aware of `atoi`, what it has to do with my question?

Comment: Please check the output I've just added.

Comment: True, I did not read everything :\ Ignore my comments. I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
auto arr = new int32_t[str.length()];
```

Then use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) as:

```
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), arr, [](char chr) -> int32_t { return int32_t(chr); });
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, this is what it does:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> str = "HELLO"
>>> np.array([str]).view(np.int32)
array([72, 69, 76, 76, 79])
```

In C/C++, `"HELLO"` already is the same thing as `[72, 69, 76, 76, 79]`!

```
static const char *s = "HELLO";
printf("%d\n", s[0]);   // prints 72
printf("%d\n", s[1]);   // prints 69
int x = s[2];   // x is now 76
printf("%d\n", x);   // prints 76
```

Comment: The code you posted is erroneous. Also, this is the default `int`, I want `int32_t`.

Comment: @YassenHatem Eh, nit-picking does not really make a difference. Anyways, now the code is no longer erroneous. If you want `int32_t` instead of `int` just replace `int` with `int32_t` in the code.